# Stop code 0x000000F8 troubleshooting

Tags: windows-7, boot, bsod, ramdisk

Stop code 0x000000F8 relates to what, exactly?  I can't find official Microsoft documentation for that specific stop code beyond:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0xf8--ramdisk-boot-initialization-failed

and to follow:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/14238/windows-10-troubleshoot-blue-screen-errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a problem inside Windows itself, you're not going to be able to solve it.

The only thing you can do is have hints what the problem was by looking at the first argument of the crash:

- 1: No LoaderXIPRom descriptor was found in the loader memory list.
- 2: Unable to open the RAM disk driver (ramdisk.sys or \Device\Ramdisk).
- 3: FSCTL_CREATE_RAM_DISK failed.
- 4: Unable to create GUID string from binary GUID.
- 5: Unable to create symbolic link pointing to the RAM disk device.

But you won't be able to figure out why the code got an error when it tried to convert a string into a GUID, or why there was a error when it tried to create a symbolic link to the RAM disk.

Comment: is this related to a "ram disk" or "ram drive"?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAM_drive

Comment: Conceptually that's what it is; but you don't know what Windows is using it for, why, or why it's failing. At the very least you could should get the first argument